# What are the RGB and HEX codes of the 3 color conditional format in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to write a script to apply the standard available three color conditional formatting to the cells. Specifically, I would like the HEX codes of the colors Excel uses. I didn't see them listed on the Web.

I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611260/what-is-the-rgb-code-for-the-conditional-formatting-styles-in-excel/65115172#65115172) question which asks for the RGB values for the 'Good', 'Neutral', and 'Bad' formatting. These are different to the colors used in the 3 color conditional formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Excel 2016 at least the colors for the cells are:

Red:

- HEX: `#f8696b`
- RGB: `(248,105,107)`

Yellow:

- HEX: `#ffeb84`
- RGB: `(255,235,132)`

Green:

- HEX: `#63be7b`
- RGB: `(99,190,123)`

Since I had to check the values and convert them to HEX manually, I figured I might as well share it.

Answer (score 0):

For red:

Font: `(156,0,6)` or `#9C0006`
Background: `(255,199,206)` or `#FFC7CE`

For green:

Font: `(0,97,0)` or `#006100`
Background: `(198,239,206)` or `#C6EFCE`

For yellow:

Font: `(156,101,0)` or `#9C6500`
Background: `(255,235,156)` or `#FFEB9C`