# Imitate Excel style gradient color effect (red, yellow, green) in gt::data_color()

Tags: r, ggplot2, color-palette, gt

With code and sample data below, I plot a gt table:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2016-1-31", "2016-2-29", "2016-3-31", 
"2016-4-30", "2016-5-31", "2016-6-30", "2016-7-31", "2016-8-31", 
"2016-9-30"), value1 = c(-15.25, -27.96, 7.53, -5.24, -6.93, 
-6.83, -6.47, 13, -10.48), value2 = c(-19.93, -13.76, 20, -11.12, 
-0.59, -9.06, 15, 1.66, -1.59)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = value1:value2,
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c(
        'red', 'yellow', 'green'),
      domain = c(df$value1, df$value2))
  )
```

[image]

Next step I attempted to achieve an **approximately same color effect** as the following plot, which I have done by the simply selecting the default 3-color scale: **red, yellow, green** from the Format Style drop-down list in Excel.

[image]

Does someone knows the values of the following hex color codes or other R's color palette could achieve same effect? Thanks.

[image]

**Update:** I obtain the similar color codes: `"#f8696b", "#ffeb84", "#63be7b"`

```
df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = value1:value2,
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c(
        "#f8696b", "#ffeb84", "#63be7b"),
      domain = c(df$value1, df$value2))
  )
```

[image]

**References:**

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/color-scales.html

[What are the RGB codes for the Conditional Formatting 'Styles' in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611260/what-are-the-rgb-codes-for-the-conditional-formatting-styles-in-excel)

Comment: this is a so-called diverging color scale, and a good option is RColorBrewer, in particular the RdYlGn palette. You can see the palette and others on https://colorbrewer2.org/#type=diverging&scheme=RdYlGn&n=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similar color palette: `c("#63be7b", "#ffeb84", "#f8696b")`

```
df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  data_color(
    columns = value1:value2,
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c(
        "#63be7b", "#ffeb84", "#f8696b"),
      domain = c(df$value1, df$value2))
  )
```

Out:

[image]